# How to get rid of this godaddy unparked screen?

Tags: godaddy, github

I redirected my Godaddy domain to Github's servers, and then waited up to **24-48 hours for DNS changes to occur**. After that, the website worked once, but after I refreshed it, this screen showed up, even after multiple refreshes. How do I get rid of this screen, and show my website?

I redirected my domain to Github by:

1. Creating a CNAME and entering the domain
2. Going over to  my GoDaddy Account
3. Manage my DNS records and add two records provided by GitHub (192.30.252.153
   192.30.252.154).
4. Save changes.
5. Wait up to 24-48 hours for DNS changes to propagate.

[image: Screen for it]

Comment: *I redirected my Godaddy domain to Github's servers* How?? Can you give us some details? Otherwise, this question is likely impossible to answer.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Is there an option where you can associate your domain name with the IP address that your web server provider gave you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain appears to be working OK for me at the moment, so this might have been a caching issue, however....

> 3. Manage my DNS records and add two records provided by GitHub (192.30.252.153 192.30.252.154).

Specifically, this is two `A` records at your DNS provider.

However, the two `A` records you have set are both pointing to the same IP address (`192.30.252.153`), so this needs to be corrected and could account for the intermittent behaviour.